# ReleaseWriterLockSlim as a Singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor Server App that is running its frontend as a Scoped process and that uses a memory cache to handle objects across requests.  Within the scoped process, it is obviously easy enough to use a ReleaseWriterLockSlim object to prevent multi-threading issues, however I need to do so across numerous instances.

I have read through several posts focused on this issue, but none appear to work as I require and I wondered if I could just create a class, expose a ReleaseWriterLockSlim as a public readonly object and then register that class as a singleton.

Shouldn't this provide the same effect no matter where it is called?  I feel that I must be missing something that will cause massive issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Web servers are inherently multi-threaded and stateless (to allow things like load balancing).  Adding any kind of thread locking is pointless, bad design, and probably will not work.  What is going to happen if there are 2 users of your Blazor app? Why do you think you need to do thread-locking?

Comment: What are you doing that requires this level of thread control?

Comment: Are there different AppDomains for these "numerous instances"?  If so, then each AppDomain will get its own Singleton instance of the RWLS, which obviously won't work.

Comment: I ended up creating singleton services for anything that needs to write to a common resource - including Blockchain Ledger, Shared Cache Objects, and similar items.  I then placed the thread locks in those classes.  The issue was running Session based objects in Blazor was causing collisions with these shared objects despite embedding the thread locks in each session object.